# CSS horizontally scroll on user swipe on overflow hidden/whitespace no-wrap

Tags: css, mobile, user-experience, usability

Is there a standard way to enable text to be pushed to the left, at least on mobile devices, when the user swipes across the element from right-to-left or vice-versa? I do *not* want to show a scrollbar and there will not be a pointer device so a `title` attribute wouldn't work.

**XML**

```
<div><span>A long line of text...</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Hello John, I found this stack overflow post about hiding the scrollbar that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll